# How to programmatically configure the settings of a CLion project (.idea files)

Tags: cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to **configure the settings of a project in CLion** (2017.2.1 or later) **programmatically** via a script or terminal commands?

Specifically, the settings (File > Settings) I would like to be able to set via a command or script are:

- those found under the **`Build, Execution, Deployment`** menu:

  - CMake/Generation/**Configuration**
  - CMake/Generation/**CMake options**
  - CMake/Generation/**Generation path**
  - CMake/Generation/**Build options**
- those found under the **`Version Control`** menu:

  - **Add**
  - Git/**Allow force push**
- etc.

---

Rationale:

The project directory contains the **.idea** directory. This is automatically created by CLion as soon as you open/import a suitable repo in the IDE. As far as I can tell, all the settings I am interesting in reside under `$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/workspace.xml` saved there after I painstakingly configure the settings of the project by hand.

According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/project.html:

> All the settings files in the .idea directory should be put under version control except the workspace.xml, which stores your local preferences. The workspace.xml file should be marked as ignored by VCS.

*However*, for cases where the above is not an option  - developers who use an IDE-independent system - it becomes quite important (for ease of use, consistency, trace-ability, etc.) to be able to automatically configure a cloned project for CLion with specific pre-defined settings.

---

What I have tried:

I have tried, copying the .idea directory of an already-configured-project in CLion over to a newly-cloned repo (which has no such .idea directory) but some settings dependent paths did not work. Also, this solution is not as elegant/straight-forward as running a script (if that is indeed a possibility)/

Furthermore, I have tried using the `Export settings` option (File > Export Settings...) but the extracted jar file does not hold any project configuration; it only holds code style, UI and other general settings.

---

I understand that CLion is not open-source but if anyone knows the necessary commands or knows of an available API or even a plugin to allow programmatically configuring these settings in a CLion project, please let me know.

Comment: There are plugins to synchronize settings through a repository (for example using Git). It's also built into newer versions of CLion. That can be used to distribute settings from a central location. ***However*** most IDE settings, except possibly code-styles, are very personal, so besides company-mandated code-styles this isn't really anything I recommend.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would greatly appreciate if you were to suggest such a CLion plugin that allows the setting of all the fields I mentioned in my question.

Comment: 1) `File | Export Settings` is for exporting IDE-wide settings (e.g. making backup / copying to another machine). 2) Project specific settings are stored in `PROJECT/.idea` folder. 3) Some settings can be marked as shared and therefore will be stored in separate xml files in that subfolder (that you can copy to another user working on the same project .. or even into another project if needs to be); the rest is stored in user-specific workspace.xml.

Comment: 4) AFAIK there is no built-in functionality to achieve what you want; You may need to generate (or alter existing after project was created; while IDE is closed) such workspace.xml yourself -- it's an XML file, so manipulating it should not be a problem in any language (XML DOM parsers ect.). You would just need to prepare such snippets (config file parts) that would be inserted into existing workspace.xml file. I personally do not have any working code for that but have read about others that were doing it for themselves for the same or similar purposes. P.S. Not using CLion myself.